# Is there any way to use a USB camera connected to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I've got an iPhone and I've got a [USB camera](https://theta360.com/en/about/theta/s.html). Is there any way to plug the camera into the iPhone and use it as the source camera for Facebook Live or other camera related items?

Comment: Why?  The iPhone's front camera is likely better.

Comment: The Theta is a full 360 camera.

Comment: What cable does that camera use?

Comment: It has a USB port and a HDMI port. Connected to the computer I can do live video over the USB port. Connected to a TV, the HDMI port.

Comment: You can go to the site of the manufacturer of the camera. If there is a specific cable and a specific software for the iPhone, then you can. Otherwise you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You should plug both your iPhone and camera to your computer. Then you sync the pictures from the camera to your iPhone. I think this is the only way it can work. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

you can search "uvc webcam to lightning"

[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide any links / Google search queries for reference.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of limitations with this setup, I found more details here: https://www.febon.net/products/usb-uvc-webcam-to-lightning